# Почему стили перебиваются?

Tags: css, media-queries, less

Есть вот такой код, написанный на less:

```
.portfolio-panel-background {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: 1s;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;


    &--active {
        width: 2000px;
        height: 2000px;
        transform: translate(-35%, -52%);



        @media screen and (max-width: 1850px) {
            width: 1600px;
            height: 1600px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1570px) {
            width: 1200px;
            height: 1200px;
        }

    }
}
```

Почему верхний media-запрос (`@media screen and (max-width: 1850px)`) перебивает нижний?

Вот так выглядит код после компиляции:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1570px) {
    .portfolio-panel-background--active {
        width: 1200px;
        height: 1200px
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1850px) {
    .portfolio-panel-background--active {
        width: 1600px;
        height: 1600px
    }
}
```

Пробовал в Less коде переставлять местами, т.е. чтобы (`@media screen and (max-width: 1850px)`) был ниже, но это не помогает, в чем проблема?

Comment: Меди запросы должны идти от большего к меньшему, не понятно почему у вас на выходе наоборот, если поменяете их местами на выходе, все должно работать

Comment: В [онлайн-компиляторе](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/) порядок правильный. Допишите в текст вопроса, где чем как именно вы компилируете, что у вас порядок получается неправильный